# Dynamic select elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I've been trying to obtain a dynamic form where one of the displayed `select` elements will change according to the value of a radio button.

**The radio button**

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="f_transfert">Transfert du défunt... : </label>
    <input name="f_transfert" type="radio" value="vers ossuaire" id="vossuaire">Vers ossuaire&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="f_transfert" type="radio" value="vers jardin du souvenir" id="vjardin">Vers jardin du souvenir&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="f_transfert" type="radio" value="vers colombarium" id="vcolumbarium">Vers colombarium
</div>
```

My page is `jsp` with `jstl` embedded, `jstl` is here used to generate html code of the wanted list. However the 3 potential `select` elements are generated with the page (no ajax and no server requests are made while the page is displayed, only using javascript to modify the DOM and the html)

I want to place in a div element (`id='transfertvers'`) the corresponding html elements, using jQuery `.add()` or `.html()` methods

```
<div class="field">
    <div>TEST JQUERY</div>
    <div id="transfertvers">
        <!-- insertion dynamique jQuery -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Until now, it's ok for retrieving the radio value with

```
jQuery('[name=f_transfert]').click(function(event){
     alert(jQuery('[name=f_transfert]:checked').val());
});
```

Now I should use a function like this:

```
switch(jQuery('[name=f_transfert]:checked').val()){
    case "vers ossuaire" :
        return ${htmloss} ;
        break;
    case "vers jardin du souvenir" :
        return ${htmljds} ;
        break;
    case "vers colombarium" :
        return ${htmlcol} ;
}
```

...to put in the document's html the expected select...

And now I feel a bit lost, because I'm not sure about what to write, and where to write it.

My jsp page includes js, and the jQuery `ready()` callback:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

I also have an independent `.js` file with functions, which I can include if needed.

Comment: I've editted your question to be a bit more descriptive and readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do add html :

```js
jQuery('[name=f_transfert]').click(function(event) {
  switch (this.value) {
    case "vers ossuaire" :
      jQuery("#transfertvers").html(${htmloss});
      break;
    case "vers jardin du souvenir" :
      jQuery("#transfertvers").html(${htmljds});
      break;
    case "vers colombarium" :
      jQuery("#transfertvers").html(${htmlcol});
      break;
  }
});
```

You can retrieve the clicked html element with the var this.

EDIT

This is because c:out print escape html. You need to print it unescape, or you can unescape it in javascript.

```js
function unescapeHTML(htmlstring) {
  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.innerHTML = htmlstring;
  return elem.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : elem.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: That's it, it works :) in the js, var is now valued like that : var oss = unescapeHTML('<c:out value="${htmloss}"/>');